# Reading recommendations for getting acquainted with cognitive behavioral therapy

Tags: cognitive-psychology, clinical-psychology

I understand the basic idea of it, but I'd like to read something beyond the Wikipedia page about it. I'll be happy to read a book, or articles online, or watch a video lecture or a documentary.

**Can you recommend *great* resources for learning about cognitive behavioral therapy?**

(Now obviously, I could find truckloads of books and information about it myself, just by using Google or my local library; what I'm looking for are *great* resources. I'm looking for the best resources of information about CBT, not just okay resources.)

Comment: Hi there!  Generally list-type questions are hard to answer.  Can you tell us more about what you're looking for?  That is, are you looking for a general overview textbook, or for something more like a workbook with exercises, etc?

Comment: Both these approaches sound good to me!

Comment: Get Aaron Beck's book, as I mentioned on the other question.  You can't get any more of a primary source.

Comment: I'll try it @ChuckSherrington , thanks! I've ordered it from Amazon :)

Comment: @RamRachum I'm glad.  He really is a genius in his own right, he took one of those "why didn't I think of that" concepts and ran with it.